# Application Error when launching my Python web app in Heroku

Tags: python, html, flask, heroku, sqlalchemy

I am unable to delpy my app I am getting an `Application Error` An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. It's a python flask based web app.

```
    2022-02-17T12:53:43.416670+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.reap_workers()
2022-02-17T12:53:43.416683+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
2022-02-17T12:53:43.416918+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
2022-02-17T12:53:43.417009+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
2022-02-17T12:53:43.569838+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-02-17T12:53:43.622927+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2022-02-17T12:53:48.830408+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=ink-brew.herokuapp.com request_id=b7e91572-f0fa-4b84-87cb-6f73672d5d2b fwd="103.204.157.38" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-02-17T12:53:49.639715+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=ink-brew.herokuapp.com request_id=d4de9715-4533-42b7-af28-71dca168d64b fwd="103.204.157.38" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-02-17T12:53:56.584056+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=ink-brew.herokuapp.com request_id=6422bc91-2df9-49c1-9ab7-70905e6ce68f fwd="103.204.157.38" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-02-17T12:53:57.039130+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=ink-brew.herokuapp.com request_id=8f758644-1e66-4997-8085-b0115dcece3a fwd="103.204.157.38" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Please help me.

Comment: It's hard to tell just from this error. I'll need more context.

But at first glance, try going to the Overview tab of your heroku project and look under Dyno Formation. check to make sure your dyno is running. you should see something with a green "ON" text next to it.

IF you don't see this, check your Procfile and make sure it's configured properly. It should be sitting in the root folder of your project.

Comment: I have this in my `web: gunicorn main:app` Procfile.
And Under `Dyno Formation` it says 
This app is using free dynos
web gunicorn main:app then ON in green color.

Comment: Please show your `main.py` file.

Comment: @chris Thank you so much mate, I solved it by removing all the unused libraries and creating new requirement.txt file and committed to the git.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by removing all the unused libraries and creating new requirement.txt file and committed to the git